# Angular 5 - stop sending multiple request

Tags: angular, interceptor

I need to stop sending multiple requests, when user clicks many times on the form submit button. So the user can't send next request until the first response is receiving. In the meanwhile he can see the spinner animation instead of this button. When response is receiving, he can click and submit again.

Not sure how to start. The button has own component, and I would like to modify the code in one place. Not sure if I need to use interceptors, directives, or what? What do you think?

Comment: Change the [disabled] property from the button.

Answer (score 3):

In the component's class create a boolean variable `isBusy` and set it to true in the `onSubmit()` method. When the result (or an error) comes back, set it back to false.

Bind the `isBusy` var to `disabled` property of the Submit button:

`<button type="submit" [disabled]="isBusy">Submit</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below mentioned package to manage the loader on a http request.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-busy

Hope this helps